# If the input is: y=1(x^3)+0.05(x^2)-2(x^1)-1 how to get the numbers form this std::string?

Tags: c++, function, loops

I've tried to make a loop to get the first number after y= 
but sometimes the value of term1coffs is: 65( 
and sometimes the value is: 65 without the bracket ?!

```
std::string fx = cwin.get_string("Enter a polynomial formula that has a form like this:     y=1(x^3)+2(x^2)+0.5(x^1)+1");

std::string j;
 //j is a condition to end for loop

int n=2; 

std::string term1coffs;
 //to get the number before the bracket y= ?? ( X^.....

for (j=fx.substr(n,1);j=="(";n+0)
{
n=n+1;
}

term1coffs=fx.substr(2,n);
double term1coff= atof(term1coffs.c_str());
```

Comment: Don't do string parsing, instead follow the logic for postfix conversion, and separate operators and operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional parsers do something like this (written in pseudocode):

```
do
{
   get a character
   if (character is operator)
   {
        store character as operator
        convert operand to double
        if conversion succeeded
            store operand value
        else
            store operand as variable name
        operand = "";
   }
   else
   {
        add current character to operand
   }
} while(there is more to do)
```

If you want to later use the parsed results to perform calculations, you probably want to produce tree-structure, based on order of precedence, taking into account parenthesis. The basic principle for this is the [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)